# <script> en next.js no funciona como espero

Tags: javascript, jquery, script, next.js

Tengo que insertar 3 scripts javascript a un componente/pagina de mi App. Dos de estos scripts tienen codigo `jQuery` (entiendo que este es mi principal problema pero tengo que insertarlo :/ )

Por particularidades, necesito que al salir del componente/pagina y volver a entrar, los scripts se ejecuten nuevamente (esto es porque los scripts se encargan de mostrar un pop-up para pagar, y si no los vuelvo a llamar en cada ingreso al componente, el pop-up no se levanta), entonces para ello tengo un hook llamado useScript que los crea/elimina, no me sirvió el componente `Script` de `Next` para estos efectos.

Este es el hook que crea y elimina los scripts al montarse/desmontarse el componente

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function useScripts(url, type, id) {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    script.type = type || "text/javascript";
    script.id = id;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // Needed for cleaning residue left by the external script that can only be removed by reloading the page
    const onRouterChange = () => {
      router.reload();
    };
    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", onRouterChange);

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", onRouterChange);

      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [router]);
}
```

Finalmente lo utilizo dentro de un componente:

```
const Component = ({
  data,
}) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  useScripts("https://i4m.i4go.com/js/jquery.i4goTrueToken.js", "text/javascript", "i4go");
  useScripts("/js/S4_new.js", "text/javascript", "S4_new");
  useScripts("https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP", "application/javascript", "ipify");

  return (
    <>
      {showModal && (
        <Modal
```

El código del script `S4` lo tengo local, y los otros dos son scripts que estan en servidores. En su interior tiene la funcion `getIP` y `calli4go_init`

```
function getIP(json) { calli4go_init(json.ip); }

function calli4go_init(uIP) {
  const url = `/api/payment/token?uIP=${uIP}`
  const jsonResponse = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => data?.results);  

  $("#form-main").i4goTrueToken({
    fuseaction: "account.authorizeClient",
    url: jsonResponse.i4go_i4m_url, // returned by endpoint
    server: jsonResponse.i4go_server,  // returned by endpoint
    accessBlock: jsonResponse.i4go_accessblock,  // returned by endpoint
    self: document.location,
    template: "bootstrap5",
    language: "en",
```

Y aca es donde tengo mi problema:

Cuando accedo al componente, a traves de mi aplicacion, pueden darse 3 escenarios:

- Recibo un error en consola diciendo que la funcion `getIP` no existe
- Recibo un error en consola diciendo que la funcion `i4goTrueToken` no existe
- Todo anda bien

Esto sucede tanto en desarrollo como en produccion.

El error es raro, debido a que si yo reinicio el navegador, accedo a mi app, me dirijo a la pagina donde se ejecutan los scripts, y lo mas probable es que reciba uno de los dos errores. Si yo vuelvo atras en mi aplicacion y vuelvo a intentarlo, ahora todo va bien.

Algunas pocas veces funciona al primer intento, pero la mayoria de las veces tengo que volver a entrar.

Entiendo que puede ser algun problema de tiempos de javascript, o que estoy haciendo algo que no esta permitido por `next.js`.

Intente hacer asincrona la funcion `calli4go_init`, hacer asincronos los scripts (agregando `script.async = true` en el hook), crear una funcion `sleep` para esperar dos segundos antes de intentar ejecutar `calli4go_init` y nada funciona.

Otra cosa que pense es enlazar de alguna manera la carga de los scripts a un useEffect con dependencias vacias (componentDidMount) pero un hook no puede ejecutarse ahi.

Cualquier sugerencia me seria de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes una condición de carrera porque no esperas correctamente a que los scripts se carguen y se interpreten. Podrías cambiar un poco ese *Hook* para añadir un estado que permita saber cuándo es posible usar el código.

Te pongo un ejemplo simplificado que carga jQuery y lo usa sólo cuando está disponible:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function useScripts(url, type, id) {
  const [scriptLoaded,setScriptLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    script.type = type || "text/javascript";
    script.id = id;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.addEventListener('load',() => {
      setScriptLoaded(true);
      console.log('Script cargado, listo para su uso');
    });
    console.log('Script añadido');
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [url]); //esto asegura que sólo se ejecute una vez
  return scriptLoaded;
}

const App = () => {
  let loaded = useScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js');
  if (loaded) {
    window.$('#test').text('Cargado');
  } else {
    console.log('Esperando la carga');
  }
  return (<span> Hola </span>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="test">No Cargado</div>
```

Comment: Pude probarlo, y me arrojo muchos menos errores que de la forma que lo tenia antes. Pero aun asi me arrojó alguna vez el error. Por eso te doy la flechita para arriba pero no le agrego tilde verde, a ver si aparece otra solucion. Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Los errores son los mismos? Sin tener un [mcve] es complicado solucionar todo

Comment: Si, el error es el mismo. Solo a veces, si tengo limpia la caché del navegador e ingreso a la parte de la app donde deberian ejecutarse los scripts, puede salir un error diciendo que no encuentra la funcion ``getIP`` (intenta usarla como callback en el 3er script, y es una funcion definida y retornada desde el script anterior que es local, ``S4_new``). Tengo que armar algo parecido en un codesandbox o similar, para dar un ejemplo exacto de lo que me pasa. Voy a tratar de hacerlo en los proximos dias, pero no se si lanzará exactamente el mismo error.